# How to call a variable which is declared inside firebase firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have some values inside my Firebase > Firestore > Collection > Document.
i can acces them by,

```
db.collection("Fund").doc("Status").get().then((doc)=>{

let MTBNAV = doc.data().SPMTB

}
```

Now, I want to Access my MTBNAV outside the function without calling another function and setting an argument

Comment: When you say you want to access it outside the function, you mean outside the then block? if it is, you can await it.

Comment: @urchmaney Cannot I do that?

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: @urchmaney Can i access MTBNAV outside .then() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the await to get MTBNAV. like this:

```
let MTBNAV = (await db.collection('Fund').doc('Status').get()).data().SPMTB
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

much easier to understand code should be:

```
const myFunc = async () => {
  const collectionRef = db.collection("Fund")
  const doc = await collectionRef.doc("Status").get()
  let MTBNAV = doc.data().SPMTB
  }
}
```